# DoCmd.SetParmeter "[enter string parameter]", stringParameter returns the error: the object "stringParameter" isn't filling the object automation

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a delete query that runs by a string parameter and it's working fine.
but when I'm using a form with a vba macro that opens and uses the query (the user enters the parameter in the form), I get the erorr that the parameter deosn't fill the object's automation. it only happens when using a string

I tried using TempVars and a string veriable both didn't work

```
DoCmd.SetParameter "[äëðñ úòåãú æäåú]", Me.Idwork.Value
DoCmd.SetParameter "[äëðñ îâáìä øôåàéú]", Me.MedWork.Value

DoCmd.OpenQuery "îç÷ áòéåú øôåàéåú", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
```

the erorr message points the the second line (Me.MedWork.Value)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I have no idea why but I needed to change the `Me.MedWork.Value` to `"MedWork.Value"`.
I'd like an explnation BTW